# union select and order by with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to select items from different tables using a union, ordered by their date (newest first)

Say I have the following tables

```
events
eventsID  | eventsTitle      | eventsTimestamp  |  eventsLocation
 1          event title         2012/08/23            1
 2          event title 2       2012/08/15            1


posts
postsID | postsSubject | postsTimestamp | postsCategory
 1          post title     2012/08/20         1
```

So the output should be

```
title           timestamp
event Title       2012/08/23 
post title        2012/08/20
event title 2     2012/08/15
```

Here's what I'm attempting to do, but I get an error from the order by

```
SELECT posts.postsID, posts.postsSubject FROM posts where posts.postsCategory = 1 ORDER BY posts.postsTimestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT events.eventsID, events.eventsTitle FROM events where events.eventsLocation = 1 ORDER BY events.eventsTimestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `ORDER BY` clause, at the end, after the 2 unioned Selects:

```
SELECT postsID          AS id, 
       postsSubject     AS title, 
       postsTimestamp   AS timestamp
FROM posts 
WHERE postsCategory = 1 

UNION

SELECT eventsID, 
       eventsTitle, 
       eventsTimestamp 
FROM events 
WHERE eventsLocation = 1 

ORDER BY timestamp DESC ;
```

Comment: Does the select statement for the events section need to devine eventsTimestamp as something?

Comment: No, the second SELECT list needs no aliases. The ones form the first SELECT list are used.

Comment: Say I want to add another table (let's call it tableB). Would I just add tableB after the events select statement and not modify anything in the posts section with the AS statements?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned under [`UNION` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html):

> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) result, parenthesize the individual [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:
>   `(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
> ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;`

Therefore:

```
 (SELECT postsSubject AS title, postsTimestamp AS timestamp
  FROM   posts
  WHERE  postsCategory = 1)

UNION ALL

 (SELECT eventsTitle, eventsTimestamp
  FROM   events
  WHERE  eventsLocation = 1)

ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c21b5/1/0).

Comment: Is there any way to distinguish between post and event once the query is executed? For example one is event.php?id=1 and the other may be post.php?id=1

Comment: @user1104854: Yes, you can include a new column in each `SELECT` - e.g. `(SELECT 'post' AS type, postsSubject ...) UNION ALL (SELECT 'event', eventsTitle ...) ORDER BY timestamp DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT Title, `TimeStamp`
(
    SELECT  posts.postsID as ID, 
            posts.postsSubject as Title, 
            eventsTimestamp as `TimeStamp`
    FROM    posts 
    where   posts.postsCategory = 1 
    UNION
    SELECT  events.eventsID as ID, 
            events.eventsTitle as Title, 
            postsTimestamp as `TimeStamp`
    FROM    events 
    where   events.eventsLocation = 1 
) x
ORDER BY `TimeStamp` DESC
```